# SharePoint foundation 2010 -Trial period for this product is about to expire

Tags: central-administration

Sharepoint foundation 2010

Central Admin

SharePoint Health Analyzer -- view issues

Trial period for this product is about to expire , should i need to be worried or is it just a bug ?

Comment: You aren't running the Beta, are you?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this the other day. It is a long shot, nonetheless:
http://retrohack.com/sharepoint-2010-trial-period-expired/

If you downloaded your bits before late April, then chances are you have the beta version installed.  Is there a link on the top right part of the page for providing feedback?

You can disable individual Health Analyzer rules, but I just checked and I don't have a rule on my server for checking expiration.

Comment: I installed SharepPoint foundation in October 2010 , also the bigger question is will it blow up or is it something which can be ignored

Comment: Did you also download it in October, or is it possible you installed from a file that was downloaded earlier?  If it is the Beta you are running, then it cannot be ignored. Have you looked at your SharePoint logs and Windows Event Viewer to see if by chance it is logging additional information? If there is an error ID in the logs, you could use it to search the knowledge base articles.

Comment: I downloaded and installed somtime in October , so that rules out beta

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. If it were me, I would not just ignore it. Definitely look at the logs to see if they shed more light. Then you may try the latest Cumulative Updates to see if they make a difference.